# Open and close NSWindow with NSButton through NSWindowController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've got a custom NSButton that I'm actually sticking in an NSStatusItem. When the NSButton is clicked, it launches my window. When the NSButton is clicked again, the window should close.

If the window is open, it appears as if the NSButton stops responding (or doesn't receive) click events! Here's the relevant code:

```
[statusItem setView:myCustomButton];
[myCustomButton setAction:@selector(showWindow:)];

- (void)showWindow:(id)sender {
    if(!myWindowController) {
        myWindowController = [[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow"];
    }

    [myWindowController showWindow:statusItem];
    [myWindowController.window orderFront:nil];
}
```

Am I doing something crazy? If I set a breakpoint in the above, it is hit when the button is clicked the first time but is not hit when the button is clicked again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're not setting a target on the button. If a button has an action but no target, it gets sent up the responder chain. When the new window is shown, the responder chain is probably being changed, which means your action is being sent to a different place.

tl;dr: try setting a target on the button.

Comment: This sounds plausible. -showWindow: is implemented on NSWindowController, so every window with a window controller could intercept that message. But since the window containing the button is always the frontmost window when you click that button, it's window controller should always intercept the message. Actually, since a window controller is being allocated in that method, that window controller ends intercepting the message, so it always shows the window. Change the method signature to something like "toggleWindow:" and see what happens.

Comment: For future googlers, I thought I'd add that I had a problem of my IBActions not being called. It was caused by my entire view controller being nil, since I had not stored it in a property after passing it on to `window.beginSheet`.